How can I stop Apple’s compiler clang impersonating gcc?
I’m trying to install the bleeding edge version of gforth according to this page
My question is not about the details of installation but about how to stop clang conflicting with GNU compiler gcc.
There are many questions in SO about this issue, I added some of them at the end.
I have a bug report filed here and I tried their suggestions as well but nothing worked. They cannot reproduce the problem because gforth compiles fine in their system. So the issue is with my Mac not with gforth.
I hope that someone with a deep knowledge of Mac OSX can help. Thanks
I’m on Sonoma 14.2, Intel
My gcc is in this location:

/usr/local/bin/gcc-14

X-Code and Developers tools are installed.
EDIT
These are the commands I issued:

Clone from git and create gforth directory
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/gforth/

cd to gforth directory

Run the script ./install-deps.sh


The script ended with
[...]
Installing /Users/a/gforth/local/bin/ccache-swig-forth
/usr/bin/install -c -d /Users/a/gforth/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 ccache-swig /Users/a/gforth/local/bin/`echo ccache-swig | sed 's&$&-forth&'`
Installation complete
/usr/bin/sudo
(base) a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air gforth 


Run ./autogen.sh

This ends with
[...]
glibtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.ac:1419: warning: The macro 'AC_HEADER_STDC' is obsolete.
configure.ac:1419: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:663: AC_HEADER_STDC is expanded from...
configure.ac:1419: the top level
(base) a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air gforth %      


Run ./configure

This ends with:
*** Config summary: Warnings exist ***

texi2html not found, HTML document won't be built.
swig not found.
Swig without -forth feature, library interfaces will not be generated.
(base) a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air gforth % 


Run make

This stopped here
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'm4', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
make: *** [prim.b] Error 72

A message appeared asking to download  the developer tools. (Already installed several times!)
m4 folder is already in the gforth directory. It contains 8 .m4 files

I downloaded the developer tools and entered make again and I got this
(base) a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air gforth % make
zsh: parse error near `a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air'

I ran ./configure again and I got
*** Config summary: Warnings exist ***
texi2html not found, HTML document won't be built.
swig not found.
Swig without -forth feature, library interfaces will not be generated.
(base) a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air gforth %

I ran make again and I got this
(base) a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air gforth % make
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'm4', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
make: *** [prim.b] Error 72
(base) a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air gforth %

I tried the last step sudo make install and I got
(base) a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air gforth % sudo make install
Password:
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'm4', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
make: *** [prim.b] Error 72
(base) a@Ahmet-MacBook-Air gforth %



Some of the questions that I tried are:
How do I make sure that my default C/C++ compiler is GCC
How to remove clang?
How to uninstall a compiler on mac?
https://ports.macports.org/port/gcc12/
Install GNU GCC on mac
My question on Superuser before I realized that the issue was related to clang:

Please show the command you issued and the error message.

@RichardBarber Thanks. I updated the question with commands and errors.

It sounds like it's looking for the m4 macro processor, not the gforth/m4 directory. You don't seem to have that installed.

@user2357112 It looks like it is installed. I tried to install with brew install m4 but it says it is already installed and up to date: Warning: m4 1.4.19 is already installed and up-to-date. And $ which m4 returns /usr/bin/m4

Hmm... googling things, it looks like you might have multiple xcode versions, or you might have installed a version of m4 that xcode doesn't know about. Have you run xcode-select --install? And what does xcode-select --print-path print?

@user2357112 `% xcode-select --print-path: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

@user2357112 % xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: Command line tools are already installed.

@user2357112 I'm downloading XCode from AppStore. It looks like it's going to take a while. I don't know if this will help.

How do go from all these errors to "clang impersonating gcc"??

@RichardBarber In my bug report here https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?66066 I was told that "my guess is that your "gcc" is actually clang, and clang takes hours for every engine compilation", so I understood this as clang acting like gcc.

@user2357112 Installing xcode again did not help. I got the same error: xcode-select: Failed to locate 'm4', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
make: *** [prim.b] Error 72

You ran ./configure without telling it which compiler to use.  Issue ./configure --help to learn how to do this.

@RichardBarber Thanks. I tried ./configure CC=gcc-14.1.0_2 but I got "cannot create executables error"
checking for gcc... gcc-14.1.0_2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in '/Users/a/gforth/gforth-0.7.9_20240801':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See 'config.log' for more details

@RichardBarber config.log: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B1DNjo7pHJBb1sclEIJG2TbN0vnzFqX9A3WDqXhaZ-U/edit?usp=sharing Warning: HUGE FILE

@RichardBarber From the log: It seems to find the gcc: configure:3475: checking for gcc
configure:3491: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3502: result: gcc

It's not picking up your gcc.  gcc exists in /usr/bin as an alias to clang.  you would need to specify the full path to your desired compiler like CC=/full/path/to/my/gcc ./configure

@RichardBarber I tried this. Terminal stops with this warning: In file included from ./engine.c:661:
prim:3394:37: warning: passing 'UCell *' (aka 'unsigned long *') to parameter of type 'Cell *' (aka 'long *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
__atomic_compare_exchange_n(a_addr, &uprev, unew, 0,
^~~~~~

Looks like success to me.  Now that we have been provided all the relevant info, I'm retracting my close vote and providing an answer, now that it's picking up your compiler.  Now you're getting code errors, which you may debug elsewhere.

You ran ./configure without telling it which compiler to use. Issue ./configure --help to learn how to do this.
Configure is not picking up your /usr/local version of gcc.

Note: gcc exists in /usr/bin as an alias to clang.
You would need to specify the full path to your desired compiler like CC=/full/path/to/my/gcc ./configure

